# Image not changing on didSelectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've used a collection view and one table view in my view and on didSelect function image is not changing.

Below is the code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell:list2TableCell = list2Table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! list2TableCell

    let image = UIImage(named: "fill-square")
    cell.tickImage.image =  image
}
```

Comment: What is cell tickImage is that a UImageView or button ? If its an imageView below answer will work out. Because it did for me. If its a button try using tickImage.setImage property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if let cell:list2TableCell =  list2Table.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? list2TableCell{
    let image = UIImage(named: "fill-square")
    cell.tickImage.image =  image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all you're doing is making a new cell that lives nowhere and changing its image — and then throwing away the cell. That's pretty silly! What you want to do is change the image of the cell that lives at the `indexPath` you were given.

Second, even doing that would be wrong. What you must do is change the image in your data *model* and then tell your table view to `reloadData`, so that `cellForRowAt` will be called and *it* will set the image in the cell.